# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to create a search bar in react that searches through TMDB API but I'm having some issues. Whenever I type into the search bar I get an error saying that `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')` and I'm not sure what the issue could be and why its returning as null. I call the mention in

```
 function Search() {
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState(""); 
  const [timeoutId, updateTimeoutId] = useState();

  const fetchData = async (searchString) => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=f134dfeac1ebb17feefa58d7f94e94cd&language=en-US&query=${searchString}&page=1&include_adult=false`);
    console.log(response);
  };

  const onTextChange = (e) => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    setSearchQuery(e.target.value);
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => fetchData(e.target.value), 500);
    updateTimeoutId(timeout);
  };

  return(
    <div> 
      <SearchBox>
      <SearchInput placeholder="SEARCH" value={searchQuery} onChange={onTextChange}></SearchInput>
      </SearchBox></div>
  );
}
```

This is the searchInput code

```
const SearchInput = styled.input`
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: 15px;
`;
```

Comment: Can you post SearchInput component code as well?

Comment: I put this into a [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-panini-30skrm?file=/src/App.js) and the error is not occurring. I agree with Yadab that the SearchInput component may be to blame.

Comment: Please update your question to include all relevant code you are working or having an issue with. What is `SearchInput` doing with the passed props? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: apologies I created the searchinput component myself. I've updated the code above

Comment: @tza00, Its working fine here even after updation https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-forked-x6gy4o

Comment: @ManirajMurugan that's strange? when I call the search function I call it in my render method for the whole application, could this be the problem? here's a link to my sandbox  and it doesnt seem to be working for me either on here https://codesandbox.io/s/lh0ev3?file=/frontend/src/App.js

Comment: @ManirajMurugan actually is it possible it could be because the function is after the render() method? I'm trying to use a combination of function and component classes

Comment: @tza00, You codesandbox doesn't render any UI.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`)

```js
function Search() {
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState(""); 
  const [timeoutId, updateTimeoutId] = useState();

  const fetchData = async (searchString) => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=f134dfeac1ebb17feefa58d7f94e94cd&language=en-US&query=${searchString}&page=1&include_adult=false`);
    console.log(response);
  };

  const onTextChange = (e) => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    setSearchQuery(e.target?.value);
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => fetchData(e.target?.value), 500);
    updateTimeoutId(timeout);
  };

  return(
    <div> 
      <SearchBox>
      <SearchInput placeholder="SEARCH" value={searchQuery} onChange={onTextChange}></SearchInput>
      </SearchBox></div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`e.target.value` does not exist anymore once the timeout has come back from the web api.  The function has ended its execution and the `e` argument won't exist anymore.

Instead, try  `useRef` instead of `e.target.value` in your `setTimeout` callback function, so when it comes back, it can reference the latest changes.

Something like this:

```
 function Search() {
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const [timeoutId, updateTimeoutId] = useState();

  const query = useRef(searchQuery);

  const fetchData = async (searchString) => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=f134dfeac1ebb17feefa58d7f94e94cd&language=en-US&query=${searchString}&page=1&include_adult=false`);
    console.log(response);
  };

  const onTextChange = (e) => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    setSearchQuery(e.target.value);
    query.current = e.target.value;
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => fetchData(query.current), 500);
    updateTimeoutId(timeout);
  };

  return(
    <div> 
      <SearchBox>
      <SearchInput placeholder="SEARCH" value={searchQuery} onChange={onTextChange}></SearchInput>
      </SearchBox></div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

After taking another look at your code I suspect it's the second event access in the timeout callback that's since been nullified. You should save a reference to the event's value within the callback scope so there isn't a dependency on the event object persisting.

```
const onTextChange = (e) => {
  const { value } = e.target;

  clearTimeout(timeoutId);

  setSearchQuery(value);
  const timeout = setTimeout(() => fetchData(value), 500);
  updateTimeoutId(timeout);
};
```

Also, FYI, unless you need the `timeoutId` as part of state to trigger a rerender or something, it's more common to use a React ref here to store a reference to the timer id. From what I can tell you are simply throttling the `fetchData` call and there is no need to trigger unnecessary renders.

Example:

```
const timeoutIdRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  // clear any running timeouts upon component unmount
  return () => clearTimeout(timeoutIdRef.current);
}, []);

...

const onTextChange = (e) => {
  const { value } = e.target;

  clearTimeout(timeoutIdRef.current);

  setSearchQuery(value);
  timeoutIdRef.current = setTimeout(() => fetchData(value), 500);
};
```